# Can't login to Ubuntu 14.04 due to ntfs partition auto mount I guess

Tags: partitioning, mount, login

I cant login to the Ubuntu 14.04 but I can access the guest user.

If I enter the correct password, it flashes and comes back to the same login screen and if I enter wrong password it mentions invalid password (so I'm not entering the wrong password)

I used disks to auto mount one ntfs partition using [this guide](https://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/howto-mount-ntfs-part-disk-in-ubuntu) before the issue started and I used mount point as /home. So I wonder if thats the issue.

Can boot in to the recovery but login using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> didn't work , it says incorrect login.
I am dual booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 and can access windows.

(I did go through other threads with same issues but none of them worked)

Answer (score 1):

Selected recovery from grub menu.
Selected root shell.

Remounted it in write mode

## mount -w -o  remount  /

Edited fstab

## nano /etc/fstab

Saved it and restated and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Login as a guest user. Then look at the contents of /etc/fstab and delete the line with the mountpoint '/home' in it.
You can do this by opening a terminal enter the command:

> sudo nano /etc/fstab

Save the file.
Then reboot and see if you can login. 
I don't know what you already tried to fix it but this could work. At the moment I can't test if you can edit fstab as a guest user so I'm not sure if it works.

You could also try the solutions in this post: [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)
The following command fixed it for me when my machine got stuck in a login loop.

> dpkg-reconfigure lightdm

Comment: AFAIK guest logins can't use sudo or obtain the rights necessary to execute dpkg-reconfigure commands. They will need to boot into recovery mode and repair /etc/fstab from a root shell. Note that it will be necessary to remount the root filesystem in read-write mode before editing the file.

Comment: You are right, can't use sudo in guest.so how can I repair fstab from root shell in recovery.I'm still at the early stages of Ubuntu, so step by step command guide will be helpful.thanks.